# Is it necessary to explicitly inherit from object?

Tags: c#, oop, object, inheritance

In [this MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.80).aspx), the class explicitly inherits from `Object`:

```
class Point: Object {
   // ...
}
```

**Is explicitly inheriting from `Object` ever necessary?**  That is, is it not equivalent to the following?

```
class Point: Object {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: `class Point {}` is compiled *exactly the same* as `class Point: object {}` or `class Point: global::System.Object {}`. (It is conceivable that a mad programmer would create their own type called Object.)

Comment: @stuartd, thanks.  Don't know how I didn't catch that.  Voted to close.

Comment: I think they just want you to know that it doesn't inherit from some other class.

Comment: @RadioSpace ..or that they are not adept at C#.. or just like to be reminded of old new-style-classes Python .. but I think that it's just baggage.

Comment: @user2864740 I am pretty sure they created C#

Comment: @RadioSpace The MSDN authors are (with perhaps rare exception) most definitely not the C# authors; and not all MSDN examples or articles are exactly stellar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is implicitly inherited. This is why every class in C# has a `.ToString()` and `.Equals()`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.object%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
Object class: "This is the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy."

This type of inheritance where everything is derived from a single class is called a "unified type system"

Comment: I've accepted your answer.  Thank you.  If anyone happens to pass by, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx) are the exceptions to the everything-inherits-`Object` rule.  (Pointer types and interface types do not.)